# Typescript class getters are not returning any data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a Typescript class that has read-only properties based on other properties in the class. The properties in question are the firstLastName and lastFirstName properties. Here is my class:

```
export interface IMember {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  active: boolean;
  readonly firstLastName: string;
  readonly lastFirstName: string;
}

export class Member implements IMember {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  active: boolean;
  get firstLastName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  get lastFirstName(): string {
    return `${this.lastName}, ${this.firstName}`;
  }
}
```

I have tried manually creating a new member object and assigning the four required properties, and I also tried creating member objects from JSON. In both cases, the code acts like the firstLastName and lastFirstName properties aren't there at all. Also, when creating the object manually, I have to mark the type as Partial, or the compiler complains that the object is missing properties (firstLastName and lastFirstName). This seems so straightforward, and I found another question here that basically showed exactly what I'm doing as the solution, but it's just not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mb You have to initialize properties.
This code works in the playground:

```js
interface IMember {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  active: boolean;
  readonly firstLastName: string;
  readonly lastFirstName: string;
}

class Member implements IMember {
  id: string = "";
  firstName: string = "first";
  lastName: string = "last";
  active: boolean = false;
  get firstLastName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
  get lastFirstName(): string {
    return `${this.lastName}, ${this.firstName}`;
  }
}

const m = new Member

console.log(m.firstLastName)
```

Comment: Initializing the properties didn't make any different for me. Those two properties are still getting returned as undefined. Is there maybe some obscure angular quirk that flattens all class properties into normal get/set properties and makes the getters not function properly?

Comment: How do you create instances?

Comment: Leaving properties without initial values might not be the direct cause of Your problem but it might prevent the TypeScript from compiling the code.

Comment: Oh, wow. Okay, I was creating my instance like this:
const test: Partial<Member> = {
      id: '0',
      firstName: 'Test',
      lastName: 'Member',
      active: true,
    };
When I tried it like this:
    const m = new Member();
    m.firstName = 'Test';
    m.lastName = 'Member';
it works! I think I can figure out how to make this work with JSON data (from Firebase) too, but it's going to be much more cumbersome than just using the spread operator and letting the mapping magic work automatically.

Comment: `const test = {}` is not an instance of `Member` class, but an object literal.
It is just a bare dictionary without any relation to the class.
You should probably use `new Member` and learn about classes in JavaScript/Typescript.

Comment: Also, `Partial` will make all of the properties in Your **type** optional, which again highlights the importance of initialization. This is a hint from the language that You are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, that's why I was declaring the object type with const test: Partial<Member>. I was under the impression that that tells the compiler that the object created from that is of Member type. I had tried just using const test: Member, but the compiler would complain that the firstLastName and lastFirstName fields were missing, even though they are read-only by virtue of not having setters. I still don't understand why it doesn't recognize that.

Comment: The line `test : Member` tells the compiler that **type** of `test` variable is `Member`.
It doesn't do the actual initialization, just adds the "protection" from assigning to `test` stuff that doesn't have **all** required properties. The `new Member` will actually make the class instantiation and `test = new Member` will assign the value to variable.
I strongly advice You to check the TypeScript tutorials. Type vs class is not a topic that can be explained here quickly and in details.